# Yahoo sent folders contains unsubscribe emails (And they aren't from me)

Tags: phishing

I continue to see emails in my sent folder that I haven't sent. I change my password and it stops for a few days only to return. What could they be? Why would yahoo send unsubscribe emails?

Example: unsubscribe@neptunecigar.com
Below that line my yahoo email is listed.

I change my password but they still come back. I've also had these emails and happen to notice if I have a file open, working on, the file shows weird symbols. Or, the file will tell me it's been corrupted.

Comment: That sounds like at least *something* is compromised, but it's hard to tell what it is.

Comment: If you're changing your password and there's still an issue, I'd be concerned that your web browser is compromised. Check your add-ons (fewer is better, more popular is better) and make sure your browser (and its add-ons), phone (if you use it for mail, plus your related phone apps) are fully up to date. Log out of Yahoo everywhere and only access it from a fresh browser profile (no add-ons) and/or your phone.